# Is there a way to preserve the existing users in VM after performing reloadOperatingSystem

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am doing a reloadOperatingSystem from a Disk Image using below rest API
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/reloadOperatingSystem
and i am able to reload OS successfully. But I am losing all my users in this process, only Admin user is there. Is there any way to preserve all existing user or to recreate all users after OS load completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try reloading from an image template, create all your users in the machine then take an image, so when you perform the reload you use your image template. You can do the proccess using the control portal to verify that your users are saved.